# list bootstrap two td table in responsive design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I design myform using bootstrap 3 table like this :

```
<table class="table table-bordered form">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="control-label">Title <span><i data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Required" class="icon-asterisk"></i></span>

            </label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3" class="">
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" value="" id="title" tabindex="1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="control-label">Author <span><i data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Required" class="icon-asterisk"></i></span>

            </label>
        </td>
        <td class="">
            <input type="text" name="sotitle" class="form-control" value="" id="title" tabindex="1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="control-label">Publisher <span><i data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="REquired" class="icon-asterisk"></i></span>

            </label>
        </td>
        <td class="">
            <input type="text" name="sotitle" class="form-control" value="" id="title" tabindex="1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="control-label">type <span><i data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Required" class="icon-asterisk"></i></span>

            </label>
        </td>
        <td class="">
            <input type="text" name="sotitle" class="form-control" value="" id="title" tabindex="1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="control-label">number <span><i data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="REquired" class="icon-asterisk"></i></span>

            </label>
        </td>
        <td class="">
            <input type="text" name="sotitle" class="form-control" value="" id="title" tabindex="1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I design title for full with and add `colspan="3"` for `td`. for other i need to `two` `td` and my form worked true But in responsive this table not good work. I need change to show list `td` in responsive like this:

[image]

How do generate this in responsive design?!

DEMO [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/4XG7T/1182/)

Comment: you can start adding a div outside the table with class "table-responsive"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you'll need to remove the table entirely, and write it with bootstraps grid structure, [**like this demo**](http://www.bootply.com/g5ErAb167d).

That will allow the inputs to stack after the page drops below a certain width (use the screen/phone toggle buttons on the right side of the demo screen to test).

Here's the pertinent code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Author</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Publisher</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Type</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Good idea, But i work with table for `table-bordered`. in your case i cant see border

Comment: That's how to get them to stack--a table won't re-order like that. You can create some CSS of your own to add borders.